# How to getting event from Event grid on successfully deplying Azure template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Say I have a https end point that can serve as a webhook url for azure event grid that I can provide in the Azure template. But that endpoint has not been validated yet. I also have an azure template that I wish for a tenant/customer to deploy. What is the way for me to receive an event that deployment of the template has finished successfully?

Comment: Do you use DevOps (https://dev.azure.com/xxxx)? Do you mean you create a service hook in DevOps? What's the meaning of endpoint has not been validated yet? Do you get any error when you create a service hook in DevOps?

Comment: Any update to this issue?

Comment: I will clarify the question a bit more. I have a customer/tenant who will deploy an ARM template say at subscription level that binds my principal to some IAM roles. The principal exists because oauth grant finished successfully. Now, once the template deployment finishes for a subcription level, I want to receive a notification. How do I do that? I did not understand your reply so I was not sure what to say

Comment: Do you use DevOps (dev.azure.com/xxxx) to do the deployment?

Comment: No, I want our product's customers who are on azure to use ARM templates to get deployed on their side via Azure CLI. And I want to find a way to know that when a customer has deployed a template at a subscription level to just get notified on our side(to an https end point or anything of that sort)

Comment: I'd like to suggest you remove `azure-devops` tag, as the query is not related to DevOps, and add `azure-resource-manager` tag to get help from ARM support.

Answer (score 0):

You may leverage Azure Monitor's capability to [view activity logs to monitor actions on resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/view-activity-logs). More specifically, you'll be interested in events from the Deployments resource (`Microsoft.Resources/deployments`).

[image: Activity Log]

From there you may create an alert rule + action group that will push the event to a webhook of your choice. You may also scope your alerting to a single resource group or a whole subscription. See [Create an alert rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-overview#create-an-alert-rule) and [Create and manage action groups in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/action-groups).

[image: Action group configuration]